# How to start a span tag from a new line only if there is a break inside it?

Tags: html, css

I have two spans inside an HTML table cell, first one is `title` and second one is `view-count`. Text inside first span is of variable length but the one inside the second span is very small e.g. `Views: 1K`. I don't want the text inside the second span to break or wrap on multiple lines. It should always appear as a single block. If there is a break inside the `view-count` span, e.g. between the words `Views:` and `1K`, entire span should start from a new line. How can I achieve this?

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
width: 100%
}

td {
width: 25%
}

.view-count {
 color: white;
 background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
 padding: 0 3px;
 border-radius: 4px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <span class="title">Variable length title.</span>
    <span class="view-count">Views: 2K</span>
  </td>
  <td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <span class="title">Variable length title. Bit longer.</span>
    <span class="view-count">Views: 2K</span>
  </td>
  <td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <span class="title">Variable length title. A little longer.</span>
    <span class="view-count">Views: 2K</span>
  </td>
  <td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: display:inline-block to view-count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the text inside the `view-count` span from wrapping by setting  `white-space: nowrap`

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
width: 100%
}

td {
width: 25%
}

.view-count {
 color: white;
 background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
 padding: 0 3px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <span class="title">Variable length title.</span>
    <span class="view-count">Views: 2K</span>
  </td>
  <td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <span class="title">Variable length title. Bit longer.</span>
    <span class="view-count">Views: 2K</span>
  </td>
  <td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <span class="title">Variable length title. A little longer.</span>
    <span class="view-count">Views: 2K</span>
  </td>
  <td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
<td>
  <span>Test string</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```